# Using lastrow variable in filter results in blank sheet

Tags: vba, excel, variables, filter

I have an issue with this code producing a blank sheet:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Range("AG" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

ActiveSheet.Range("$AG$1:$AG$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "FS Cable OR Bend In/Service Group"
```

And yes, that last line is accurate, there are values in column AG that have that exact verbiage. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is sheet1 the active sheet?

Comment: I just created a dummy "Sheet1", added some random numbers into about 45 rows of column AG, then changed some of those to be the string `"FS Cable OR Bend In/Service Group"`, then ran your exact code ... and it correctly filtered to show those rows where I placed the string.

Comment: OK, I screwed up, but I honestly don't know why this would cause this problem.  I missed a step right before the filter to copy all visible data into a new blank workbook...resetting the row numbers.  Once I did that, this code worked fine.  I'm new but I'm also a little slow on the take!  Sorry, and thanks for testing it.